# ID request - small green caterpillar

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This was eating my mustard spinach (Brassica rapa subsp. nipposinica) plant in Washington state, USA; about 1cm in length.
[image: green caterpillar]

Comment: That's a really beautiful photo! Can I ask how you got it on such a pure white background and yet the hairs show up so nicely?

Comment: @uhoh Thanks! I spent quite a lot of time editing the image: used various masks to select non-green and almost white things and make them white.

Comment: I don’t know the exact species but he is a type of inchworm.

Comment: I was going to say *Pieris* (cabbage white), but those aren't "inchworms".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went to images.bing.com and typed *Brassica pest lepidoptera*, which led immediately to photos of the [cabbage looper (*Trichoplusia ni*)](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/help-for-the-home-gardener/advice-tips-resources/pests-and-problems/insects/caterpillars/cabbage-looper.aspx)

I thought [this image](https://www.knowlesville.com/matt/fauna/insects/cabbage-looper-008/) was particularly persuasive.

Comment: Nicely done, I don't know how I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Found it using the terms "inchworm species washington" in google.

It is the [Winter Moth](https://www.massaudubon.org/learn/nature-wildlife/insects-arachnids/winter-moths) (*Operophtera brumata*). This is a common species of invasive pest in the USA and Canada, introduced from Europe. It is an "inchworm" or "looper" as they are known colloquially. The caterpillars have yellowish rings on the body at the segments and longitudinal white stripes.

Comment: I don't think this is Operophtera brumata. The host plant is different, the time of year is different, coloration/marks are different.

Comment: @SergiiDymchenko - I agree; see Mike Serfas's answer, looks like the right one.